# Compare two lists with same elements but in opposite order using java

Tags: java, list, compare

I have two lists `A` and `B` which have same elements but in opposite order like `A = a, b, c, d` and `B = d, c, b, a`. I want to compare these two lists and want result as "not same". I have tried equals method but its giving me output as "same".
below is the code

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
        List<WebElement> rowsTable = table.findElements(By.xpath(""));
        List<String> listActual = new ArrayList<String>();
        int rowsCount = rowsTable.size();
        for (int i = 1; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            List<WebElement> rowColumns = (rowsTable.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("")));
            listActual.add(rowColumns.get(0).getText());
        }
        System.out.println(listActual);
        List<String> listExpected = listActual;
    
       Collections.sort(listExpected, Collections.reverseOrder(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
        System.out.println(listExpected);
            if (listExpected.equals(listActual)) {
                System.out.println("List is sorted");`
} else {
                System.out.println("List is not sorted");
            }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that's producing that result?

Comment: i have pasted the code above @ernest_k

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `List<String> listExpected = listActual;` statement: listExpected is a reference now pointing to the listActual, it's NOT a new, separate list, and so "Collections.sort" sorts listActual, actually. Convince yourself: after "Collections.sort", put another `System.out.println(listActual);`, I guess you'll get the sorted list then.
Instead of just putting another reference to the same object ("listExpected = listActual"), create a new list, a real copy of the data, try:
`List<String> listExpected = new ArrayList<String>(); Collections.copy(listExpected, listActual);`